# Creating an android login/registration system using REST API

Tags: android, json, rest, authentication

All I got is REST API link which contains JSON data. I have to create a login/registration system in android native system. I have no idea how can I proceed with REST. Need help.

Comment: Use google. Retrofit might be a nice lib to implement.

Comment: I found a library called Volley. Can you tell me whether I can implement it with volley or not? Also, it would be great if you could share some content regarding this. @Stefan

Comment: Personally i prefer retrofit, if you search for retrofit tutorial you will find something. Volley works as well

Comment: Can I cache data using retrofit? If yes, Should I explicitly define the cache system or it is default

Comment: You have to write your own implementation, with something like ORM lite

Answer (score 0):

You can use retrofit or volley for requests and Gson for parsing and serializing JSON.
here is some useful link

retrofit: http://square.github.io/retrofit/
sample for retrofit: https://github.com/atahani/retrofit-sample
check this class for rest endpoint: https://github.com/atahani/retrofit-sample/blob/14_final/app/src/main/java/com/atahani/retrofit_sample/network/FakeTwitterService.java

volley: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

GSON: https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: I have looked through some volley tutorials. But, regarding the login/logout system most of them are using a php script. But, all I got is the REST api link, so that I can get and post data. Realllly stuck bro.

Comment: @SoumyaRauth volley and Retrofit both can work with rest api. Especially Retrofit designed for rest api.  I edit my answer and add some samples.